# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=1.1.2.0 error on asp.net core 1.1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I upgraded to `VS2017 15.3.3` but still working on an `ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1.1` project with `code first` approach. When following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db) from official ASP.NET team (that is geared more towards ASP.NET Core 2.0) when I ran the following `Package Manager` command (from the tutorial) I was getting compatibility error (`v2.0 vs v1.1`):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

So, I decided to add the `-version 1.1.1` as a parameter to the above command as follows and it ran successfully:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -version 1.1.1
```

I did the same for other two related `PM` commands in the above mentioned tutorial and everything ran fine. But now, when I run the following PM command I get the following error:

```
PM> add-migration MyFirstMigration -context BloggingContext
```

**Error**

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=1.1.2.0

**.csproj** File

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-MVC_IndvUserAccts_Test-B2520DA6-BE8D-42EE-806D-366F7C4C2E77</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: can you post all of the assembly references in your csproj  please.

Comment: @mvermef Sure. Per your request, I just added `.csproj` file content.

Comment: running `add-migration somemigrationname -Context BloggingContext` gets that error? the add-migration you indicated would actually error out..
install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 1.1.2 should be correct.   Also is BloggingContext the only one?

Comment: @mvermef 1. Yes, actually I'm running  `add-migration MyFirstMigration -Context BloggingContext` (thank you for pointing that out - I've just corrected that in my post). 2. Since the app is using Individual User Account authentication mode the other DbContext is `ApplicationDbContext` that Visual Studio creates by default if choosing an Authentication mode.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have faced the same issue at my office system what help me to solve the problem is:

**dotnet remove package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design** -(system assembly 2.2.1.0 which was causing the error)

**dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design --version 2.2.0** -the correct assemly (Target assembly that is needed to my project)

Answer (score 0):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

**DotNeCliReference**

```
<DotNetCliToolReference   Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.1" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
```

Comment: I see the two items you're displaying are not only showing version numbers different but their other attribute names are also different. So exactly what you suggest I need to do?

Comment: my suggestion is to give that a whirl since those work presently in my solution.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). I just changed Version `1.1.1` to `1.1.2` in the following and it worked `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />`. For the benefit of other readers you may want to clarify your `Reply` a bit more and I'll mark that as an answer. I myself was not clear what you were suggesting me to do until you sent your comments.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't exactly clear either glad it worked out nonetheless.